# How to trigger tap event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch

I need to set `tap` trigger on some selectors. I'm using jQuery Mobile and this function, so what is not right?

```
window.onload = load;

function load() {
  $('.togglePlay').trigger('tap');
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use $.ready function instead of window's onload event

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: i need to automaticly fireup some video on ipad... so i'm trying to simulate pla ybutton click

Comment: `$(document).on('pageshow', '#pageid', function () { ur trigger });`

Comment: what is the `#pageid`? do i need this?

Comment: Hmmm, aren't you using JQM? Don't you have divs with data-role=page?

Comment: i'm trying use it only for this event :)

Comment: I know it's a while since you post this but people can still benefit from your question and its answers. 2 questions : your code actually worked? and why not just use the click event?

Comment: @user10089632 sory man but i don't remember this case, this was at 2013 :) also haven't used jQuery since more then year now

Answer (score 1):

Look into [tap](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) and [taphold](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) touch event.

```js
// The tap event won't be emitted along with the taphold event
$.event.special.tap.emitTapOnTaphold = false;

$("#fire").on("taphold", function() {
  $(this).addClass("colorize");
});
$("#banana").on("tap", function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.colorize {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<h3>If you tap and hold me for 750 milliseconds, I will fill up with color.</h3>
<span id="fire"></span>
<hr />
<h3>If you tap me quick, I will dispear.</h3>
<span id="banana"></span>
```

Comment: For Your  second sentence, You may need to set `$.event.special.tap.emitTapOnTaphold` to `false`. See here:https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.togglePlay').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: `.ready` shouldn't be used with jQuery Mobile http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1771795

Comment: oh i see.. i don't know about mobiles.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the loading page has a div containing `data-role=page` and its `id` is `mypage`, you could use the `pageinit` event to fire up the `click` on `'.togglePlay'` like this  :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mypage", function () {
  $('.togglePlay').trigger('click');
});
```

**References**

- For reasons why you mustn't use `ready` event with jQM, see [jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events/14469041#14469041)
- Link for page events from jQM API : [Events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/)

Comment: he want to trigger a tap , not a click.

Answer (score -1):

I use jQuery tap() method.

```
$('.togglePlay').tap();
```

http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

This works for me :)

Answer (score -2):

you should be able to set autoplay=true or some other setting with...

```
<video controls autoplay>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

example from: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp

without the use of js

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question asked